# Forcing ArcGIS for Desktop to generate color pallettes for display of GeoTiffs in FAIMS Mobile App?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.1, geotiff-tiff, faims

The [FAIMS Mobile App](https://www.fedarch.org/wordpress/development/information-for-developers/) <sup>1</sup> displays a black pane instead of a well rendered geotiff when I try to import files directly from ArcGIS 10.1 instead of processing them through gdal and grass.

Running gdalinfo, the major difference between pre and post processing with GRASS is the presence of:

> ```
> Band 1 Block=256x256 Type=UInt16, ColorInterp=Palette
>   Color Table (RGB with 65536 entries)
>     0: 5,5,5,255
>     1: 5,5,5,255 
>
> ...
>
>   65534: 0,0,0,255
>   65535: 0,0,0,255
> ```

The ArcGIS produced Geotiffs by our resident mapping person do *not* have this, unfortunately.

I know a limitation of the Nutiteq rendering engine the app uses requires either this color palette or the kind of tiff that shows up normally when viewed with a normal image viewer.

Our normal [prep methodology](http://wiki.fedarch.org:8090/display/FAIMS/Importing+GeoTiffs+into+FAIMS+Android+App) is kind of painful, and I'm wondering if there isn't a simpler solution.

Is there a way to force ArcGIS to generate a geoTIFF that:

1. Is in the required projection for display (EPSG:3857),
2. equivalent to -co TILED=YES (I know tiled means many different things, so this is the tiled of gdalwarp)
3. And has a written colour pallette for the UInt16 that it needs?

<sup>1</sup>Fair disclosure, I'm one of the FAIMS project leads.

Comment: Can someone also create the FAIMS tag? I'm happy to drop in a tag wiki, I simply don't have enough rep to tag appropriately.

Comment: This seems like the first question about FAIMS. Could you add a link in your question as well as ArcMap version?

Comment: Thanks Paul. To be clear, I'm one of the devs of FAIMS (And I believe that this is an appropriately technical question for the GIS stack). I linked to our "here's our links" page. I know our [map support](http://wiki.fedarch.org:8090/display/FAIMS/Program+Logic+Support) can't deal with the esoteric geotiffs we keep getting and I'm trying to figure out if there's a better method than [this](http://wiki.fedarch.org:8090/display/FAIMS/Importing+GeoTiffs+into+FAIMS+Android+App)

Comment: I just added the [tag:faims] tag for you.

Answer (score 1):

To have ArcGIS for Desktop, or ArcGIS Pro, generate a GeoTIFF that meets your requirements, I suspect that you will need to submit an [ArcGIS Idea](https://geonet.esri.com/community/arcgis-ideas).